# Claroline How to switch from single database mode to multiple database mode

Tags: mysql, database, content-management-system

We are using [Claroline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claroline) www.claroline.net LMS(Learning Management System) for E-learning, and the guy who installed it chosen "single database mode" which generates a LOT of tables! he said that the hosting service does not accept the "multiple database mode". But now our database is very huge and slow because of hundreds tables and just the schema size is up to 17Mo, actually i can't export the database, can't even see the tables through phpMyAdmin, i can't do a backup (too slow, doesn't work). And the amount of tables keeps growing.

Is there any way to solve that problem, because we are going to loose our data. Our web hosting service is OVH

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. In multidb mode, you have the same amount of "table" but in many databases.
2. The only way to "reduce" the number of table is to store all datas of all courses in sames tables.
   So rewrite  all queries to add a "where course=$cid".
   Too many work.
   -> perhaps by using a "statement rewriter" in the code to add  the "where course=$cid" on fly.

*I leave Claroline team  7-8y ago so perhaps something is new on this aspect.*